# Case command in Scheme language

Tags: switch-statement, scheme, lisp

I am trying to understand how to use `case` command with variables in Scheme

```
(define CONSTANT 5) 
(define x 5)
(case x ((CONSTANT) "equal") (else "not equal"))
```

The above example results in "not equal". Why?

Note that the following example works:

```
(define CONSTANT 5)
(define x 5)
(case x ((5) "equal") (else "not equal"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/case.html), it's stated that:

> The selected clause is the first one with a *datum* whose [`quoted`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quote.html#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._quote%29%29) form is [`equal?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._equal~3f%29%29) to the result of `val-expr`.

The key word here is **"quoted"**. The expression in the clause is not evaluated, is taken literally as it was written. So in fact you're trying to match against the *symbol* `'CONSTANT`. We can verify this:

```
(define x 'CONSTANT)

(case x
  ((CONSTANT) "equal")
  (else "not equal"))

=> "equal"
```

**UPDATE:** From the comments, it appears that you need to match an element against a list of constants. A `cond` + `member` will  work better:

```
(define CONSTANT1 1)
(define CONSTANT2 2)
(define CONSTANT3 3)

(define x 3)
(define constants (list CONSTANT1 CONSTANT2 CONSTANT3))

(cond ((member x constants) "equal")
      (else "not equal"))

=> "equal"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I wrote this minimum working example because I am writing a function to check the return vallue of another function that I did not write, so x is returned from a function and I need to check if it is found in an array of constants.

Comment: @Leptoceratops ok, but as I said above: you simply can't put variables in a clause of a `case`. Maybe if you just wrote a list with the values of the constants? Or how about using `member` and a plain old `cond`?

Comment: @Leptoceratops I'm not sure I understood your comment, did my answer solve your problem, or at least explained why your approach won't work? If you still require assistance, please edit the question adding additional details.

Comment: Yes. The combination of `cond` and `member` works for me. Thank you!